# How do I mount CD-ROM at /media/cdrom0?

Tags: mount, wine, cd, games, playonlinux

I'm trying to install a game of mine using POL (PlayOnLinux), but the CD-ROM must be mounted at /media/cdrom0. Instead, it is being mounted at /media/(diskname). Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Ran into the same issue trying to install a wireless driver on a fresh ubuntu install - the disk has to be mounted at /media/cdrom in order to install packages from it. Unmounting and remounting in the correct spot fixed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First Unmount it:

```
sudo umount /media/(diskname)
```

Then mount it where you want:

```
mount -t auto /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom0
```

I think there is another (easier) solution to your problem: just make a symbolic link:

```
sudo mkdir /media/cdrom0

sudo ln -s /media/(diskname) /media/cdrom0
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help. After I enter in the second command, it tells me that cdrom0 does not exist, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sadly, I had to find another way to install the game, the POL script was very outdated and didn't work for me.

Comment: You should create the folder before. I edited the answer. Glad you find a way to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Even though I found another way to get the game working, I will keep this bookmarked as it will come in handy, I have a LOT more to install.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *bind mount*. It allows you to have more than one mount point for a device. For instance,  `sudo mount -o bind /media/dvd0 /media/cdrom0` would make `/media/cdrom0` identical to `/media/dvd0`.